# Подключить chromium headless в Electron

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

Приветсвую!

У меня есть приложение на Electron (vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder)

Я хочу вызвать из интерфейса chromiumdriver и фоново получить HTML страницы удаленного SPA сайта.

У меня в голове два варианта:

- понять как вызвать по запросу окно браузера электрона с параметром --headless и спрасить страницу
- написать nodejs скрипт и вызвать его из интерфейса

Я пока что пошел по второму варианту:

```js
const remote = require('webdriverio').remote;

let browser;

async function f() {
  try {
    browser = await remote({
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // todo get path from electron
        // chromeOptions: { binary: '...'},
      },
    });

    await browser.navigateTo('http://mysite.com/');

    const title = await browser.getHTML();
    return title;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    browser.deleteSession();
  }
}

module.exports = f;
```

Но не получается из интерфейса вызвать nodejs скрипт...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение

UI:

```js
  methods: {
    myFunction() {
      ipcRenderer.send('node:getHtmlPage', { key: '1', url: 'https://furyferret.com' });
      ipcRenderer.on('node:getHtmlPage', (event, payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
      });
      // todo dont't work ?
      // ipcRenderer.invoke('some-name', { nickname: 1, site: 'er' }).then((result) => {
      //   console.log(result);
      // });
    },
  },
```

Background.js > import your js file

```js
import { ipcMain, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

const EVENT_KEY = 'node:getHtmlPage';

function pause(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
}

async function getHtmlPage(url) {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({});
  await win.loadURL(url);
  await pause(5000);
  const html = await win.webContents.executeJavaScript('document.documentElement.innerHTML');
  return html;
}

ipcMain.on(EVENT_KEY, async (event, { key, url }) => {
  getHtmlPage(url)
    .then((html) => {
      event.sender.send(EVENT_KEY, {
        key, url, html, isSuccessful: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      event.sender.send(EVENT_KEY, { key, url, isSuccessful: false });
    });
});
```

---